# Not able to install TestNG on Eclipse Neon. Getting prompt for Username and password

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng, eclipse-neon

After clicking `Help > Eclipse Marketplace` and search TestNG and then hitting on install I am being asked to enter credentials for `beust.com`

Pop up title: `Login required`

```
Please provide login details for beust.com

Username:
Password:

(Save password checkbox)

[Ok]     [Cancel]
```

Comment: I have just started getting these for an update of an already installed TestNG plugin

Answer (score 1):

It is a known issue: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/334

You can follow it there.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to follow in Eclipse:

1. Click on Help Menu
2. Click New Software install
3. Click on Add and Type TestNG and type url as = https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/
4. Click Next
5. Select TestNG and click next
6. Accept license and Finish.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center. –

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to install TestNG :

**Way 1:** The latest version of TestNG can be downloaded from Maven Central.

For the Eclipse plug-in, we suggest using the update site:

Select Help / Software updates / Find and Install.

Search for new features to install.

New remote site.

For Eclipse 3.4 and above, enter http://beust.com/eclipse.

For Eclipse 3.3 and below, enter http://beust.com/eclipse1.

Make sure the check box next to URL is checked and click Next.

Eclipse will then guide you through the process.

After installation follow the steps below:

1. Restart eclipse
2. Go to Window-> Preferences and observe the left panel
3. TestNG is enlisted

For Installation details visit the following site:

http://testng.org/doc/download.html

**Way 2:** TestNG can also be installed in Eclipse by using Marketplace. Below are the steps:

Open eclipse

Go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace...

Do search for TestNG (Type the text TestNG in Find text box > Click Go button)

After searching: Click Install button at TestNG for Eclipse area

Follow the further instructions by eclipse

Hope one of above solution will work out.

Answer (score 0):

Simply enter a username and password (Like you are signing up to a site) and click OK. TestNG will be installed. You may require this login credentials in future if you need to update/modify testNG. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

provide blank space as user id & password .
then click on save password checkbox . 
it should resolve the installation issue.